# Call back function is not executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function where the target is to direct my application to the next page.
The user must click ok and the function must be executed.
In this case the function does not seem to be executed when clicking the button, to confirm this I put some console.log("") that should be executed when clicking the button, but they are not called.

Explaining the logic better, I have a "main" page which is where the function was created, where I execute the logic, including console.log("")

```
const modalSkipClicked = async () => {
console.log('TEST HERE')
await loadNextPage([CALIBRATION], RESULT.DECLINED)
```

}

It is passed to another component which is my error screen, this screen is where the button appears and where console.log("") should appear.
To do this, I pass this function via "props".

```
{showFullscreenError && (
    <div data-testid="full-screen-error">
      <FullscreenError
        alert={errorCategory}
        onContinue={modalSkipClicked}
        icons={cartridges}
        analytics={{
          screenName: SCREENS.PRINT_ALIGNMENT_FULLSCREEN_ERROR,
          mode: MODES.UI[isCurrentActionAuto],
          controls: {
            skip: CONTROLS.SKIP,
            retry: CONTROLS.RETRY
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )}
```

In my other screen that I call FullscreenError, I operate this function via props.

```
const { alert, onContinue, icons, analytics } = props
```

And I pass this "onContinue" prop to another component, which is the button.

```
{!isBlocking && (
        <NextStageButton
          dataTestId="warning-button"
          onClick={() => {
            fireButtonClick(CONTROLS.CONTINUE, {
              mode: analytics.mode
            })
            onContinue
          }}
          copy={
            isSingleCartridgeOrCounterfeit
              ? getText('common.continue')
              : getText('common.ok')
          }
        />
      )}
```

Within this button, the function should be executed.

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Button from '@veneer/core/dist/esm/scripts/button'

const NextStageButton = ({
  copy,
  onClick,
  dataTestId,
  appearance = 'primary',
  disable = false
}) => {
  const [buttonPressed, setButtonPressed] = useState(false)

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setButtonPressed(true)
    console.log('inside of handler')
    console.log('OnClick ->>>> ', onClick)
    onClick()
  }

  return (
    <Button
      disabled={disable}
      appearance={appearance}
      data-testid={dataTestId}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
      loading={buttonPressed}
    >
      {copy}
    </Button>
  )
}
```

export default NextStageButton

It's interesting that all the other button elements work, even the loading spinner, but the function doesn't work and the log doesn't appear.

Comment: The Problem has been discovered, apparently it is not right to send a callback function without the ().

Answer (score 0):

The Problem has been discovered, apparently it is not right to send a callback function without the ().
It was necessary to add them in front of **onContinue**.

```
{!isBlocking && (
    <NextStageButton
      dataTestId="warning-button"
      onClick={() => {
        fireButtonClick(CONTROLS.CONTINUE, {
          mode: analytics.mode
        })
        onContinue()
      }}
      copy={
        isSingleCartridgeOrCounterfeit
          ? getText('common.continue')
          : getText('common.ok')
      }
    />
  )}
```